# Задержка telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core

Пишу телеграм бота на asp.net core. Проблема заключается в том, что, если боту какое-то время (от 2.5 минут) не отправлять сообщения, то первый запрос после этого промежутка времени он обрабатывает гораздо дольше. На скрине я попытался все наглядно показать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для тестирования я полностью скопировал [этого](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/tree/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook) эхобота. Бота запускал как с помощью ngrok, так и деплоил на сервер. Пробовал запускать без iis (только Kestrel). Ставил stopwatch, чтобы узнать, что занимает столько времени, этим оказалась команда sendMessage. Но когда я делал бота без вебхуков такой проблемы не было. Не понимаю в какую дальше двигаться сторону для решения проблемы

Comment: Вероятно, бот хостится в IIS, а там настроено засыпать процессу через 2.5 минуты. Либо убирайте засыпание (и иногда для этого нужно купить нормальный тариф у хостера, где не режут дико лимиты), либо если надо дёшево и сердито - пишите скрипт, который будет пинговать сервис каждые 2 минуты.

Comment: Уже пробовал запускать у себя на пк без проксирования через IIS, результат тот же