# Долгое выполнение запросов HttpClient

Tags: c#, http

Если посылать запросы через HttpClient c интервалом примерно 2.5 минут и более, они выполняются гораздо медленнее. Покажу на примере

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(async (e) => {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        }, null, 0, 20000); //интервал менее 2.5 минут

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Я получаю *924 259 270 258* и так далее, время выполнения в районе 200-300 мс

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(async (e) => {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
        }, null, 0, 150000); //интервал 2.5 минут и более

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Получаю *935 549 478 551*, то есть, можно сказать, в два раза дольше.

С чем это связано и как можно исправить?

Comment: Что исправить? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1292609/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-telegram-bot

Comment: А если так? `using var response = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");` и при чем тут гет запросы в гугл и пост запросы в API?

Comment: Может у вас там прокси какая-нибудь принудительная стоит, которая кэширует запросы, если между ними мало времени прошло )  И вообще я бы на другом каком сайте попробовал, как работает гугль внутри себя - дело загадочное

Comment: А если не `sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds`, а `sw.ElapsedMilliseconds`? Что такое  924 259 270 258?

Comment: @aepot эти цифры - миллисекунды. Попробовал `using var response = await client.GetAsync("https://google.com");` - никакой разницы. В API дело именно в долгой отправки сообщения (http запроса к телеграму)

Comment: Еще раз, при чем тут телеграм, если в коде гугл? Запросы к гуглу нормально работают?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на первую цифру. Одинаковая? +- да. Почему? Наверно потому, что первый запрос открывает соединение, а последующие используют его, не открывая повторно. Если вы делаете "долгие" промежутки, то это соединение, наверно, "протухает", а значит надо потратить снова время на его восстановление. Догадки конечно, но весьма логичные. Попробуйте понаблюдайте через консоль за соединенями (что-то на подобии `netstat -n | select-string -pattern "ip гугла"`.

Comment: @aepot все работает так, как я написал в вопросе, вне зависимости от сайта к которому я посылаю запросы

Comment: А, до меня только сейчас дошло, что означает девятьсот двадцать четыре миллиарда двести пятьдесят девять миллионов двести семьдесят тысяч двести пятьдесят восемь миллисекунд. Какую версию дотнета используете?

Comment: @aepot .net 5, на других еще не пробовал

Comment: .NET 5 норм, значит смотрите/гуглите, как настраивать `SocketsHttpHandler` для `HttpClient`, чтобы получить желаемое вами поведение. Заодно и узнаете, как оно там внутри работает. И не используйте таймеры с асинхронным кодом. Есть же обычный цикл и `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: Решил чуть поколдовать, сделать чтоб было наглядно видно, что и как. Получил [такой код](https://pastebin.com/A1S87Lfj), запустите у себя ради интереса, посмотрите, что будет, данные конечно не слишком точные (да и не нужны они там точные), но для общей картины думаю будет достаточно. У меня получилось [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n08BL.png), можно заметить, что было 4 запроса, а также можно заметить, что предыдущий статус соединения всегда `TimeWait`, что означает "Сокет закрыт, но ожидает пакеты, ещё находящиеся в сети для обработки". А также обратите внимание на IP, почти всегда новый.